# Why do Jupyter Notebook cells have left padding?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[image: The padding]

The Jupyter Notebook code cells in Visual Studio Code appear padded from the left cell margin, which was not the case a few days ago. This is only an issue with the Jupyter Notebook cells, normal Python does not have any padding.

Is there a way of removing it? I do not remember changing anything about the general Appearance of the editors or anything in the Python extension.

Comment: send question to authors of Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

This is may caused by the the changes for multiple languages in the latest version。
For temporary solution, you can download the previous version 2020.5.86806 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases/tag/2020.5.86806

and install this by VXIS. Then it will be fine.